# Macro defined in main.c not visible in another included file

Tags: c, gcc, macros, avr-gcc

I have multiple C and H files

In `main.c` I defined a macro, and in `ws_driver.c` I want to use it.

`ws_driver.h` is included in `main.c`.

*main.c*

```
#define WS_PORT PORT_D8
#define WS_BIT D8
#define WS_DDR DDR_D8

#include "ws_driver.h"
```

In `ws_dirver.c` I have two checks:

*ws_driver.c*

```
#include "ws_driver.h"

#ifndef WS_PORT
# error "WS_PORT not defined!"
#endif

#ifndef WS_BIT
# error "WS_BIT not defined!"
#endif
```

Both are failing.

```
$ avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -Os -I. -I -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-main -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-comment -g2 -ggdb -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--relax -std=gnu99 main.c  ws_driver.c --output main.elf
ws_driver.c:10:3: error: #error "WS_PORT not defined!"
 # error "WS_PORT not defined!"
   ^
ws_driver.c:14:3: error: #error "WS_BIT not defined!"
 # error "WS_BIT not defined!"
   ^
ws_driver.c: In function 'ws_show':
ws_driver.c:23:20: error: 'WS_PORT' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define bus_low() (WS_PORT) &= ~(1 << WS_BIT)
                    ^
ws_driver.c:37:2: note: in expansion of macro 'bus_low'
  bus_low();
  ^
ws_driver.c:23:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define b......
```

What am I doing wrong? Please ask if you want to see some other part of the code.

Comment: Maybe remove the spaces before error: `# error`

Comment: You should not include source files. Your `main.c` isn't included. You included the `.h` file from your `main.c`, not the other way around.

Comment: @BennoZeeman I don't include any `c` file anywhere, what do you mean?

Comment: Your post does not seem very clear to me. It looks like you're defining your constants in `main.c` and not in `ws_driver.h`, which would explain why `ws_driver.c` does not see them.

Comment: The point is that ws_driver.c (and h) are meant to work as a library. Those macros are configuration for them. How else should I pass it?

Comment: define a `config.h` that sets the values of your configurable ports and includes `ws_driver.h`, then include it in both your `.c`files?

Comment: Yeah that might work, but is that the proper way of doing it? If I want to distribute `ws_driver` as a library, everyone would have to make their own `config.h`? (Or maybe I'm not getting something.. dunno. Perhaps put everything that is now in `ws_driver.c` into `ws_driver.h` file? That's not good tho, I guess)

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your structure when you're defining `define`s in your `main.c` and using them in your library files.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that much from your comments. Say, usually, if there's a library with configuration like this - where do you define it then? In the makefile as -Dsomething?

Comment: You can define them in your `ws_driver.h`, or make a separate `config.h` for all your `define`s. I think that's the most conventional and convenient way to do it.

Comment: ok, it's clearer now. thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to define the macros in a header file, not in the .c file if you want to use them in multiple places.

When the compiler compiles `ws_driver.c` it only includes `ws_driver.h` and the macro is not there. It does not include main.c. Each .c file is compiled separately.

Move the macro definitions in say `config.h` and include it everywhere you need it.

You can also use the compiler's define `-DWS_BIT=123 -DOTHER=SMTH`. The value you pass will be in the generated object file and can not be changed without recompiling.

If you want to compile only once, then pass these as parameters or create a  `configure_my_library()` function...

Comment: "You have to define the macros in a header file, not in the .c file" - thanks for that!